# Advanced Php Number Formatting

Tags: php, number-formatting

I want to have a PHP number formatted with a minimum of 2 decimal places and a maximum of 8 decimal places. How can you do that properly.

Update: I'm sorry, my question is say I have number "4". I wish for it to display as "4.00" and if I have "2.000000001" then it displays as "2.00" or if I have "3.2102" it will display as such. There is a NSNumber formatter on iPhone, what is the equivalent in PHP.

Comment: How do you propose to decide which number of decimal places is used for a given number?

Comment: How many do you display for `2.120000001`?

Comment: Im sorry, my question is say I have number "4". I wish for it to display as "4.00" and if I have "2.000000001" then it displays as "2.00" or if I have "3.2102" it will display as such. There is a NSNumber formatter on iPhone, what is the equivalent in PHP.

Comment: Can you provide some examples and tell us what you've tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: I have just been displaying the number raw. I wanted to hear from people with experience so I don't spend hours doing something completely off track. I know there is someone out there who knows what they are doing! (:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This formats the $n number for 8 decimals, then removes the trailing zero, max 6 times.

```
$s = number_format($n, 8);
for($i=0; $i<8-2; $i++) {
    if (substr($s, -1) == '0')
        $s = substr($s, 0, -1);
}
print "Number = $s";
```

Comment: Wow! That is smart. Let me try it

Comment: Does this work if the number is 40.0012?  Also explain your answer a little bit more instead of just posting code.

Comment: @JPM: formats number for 8 decimals, then removes the trailing zero, max 6 times. it's a pretty obvious code.. does it really need an explanation?

Comment: @yi_H: What if someone is a new PHP programmer he wouldn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format a number to a certain number of decimal places:

```
$decimal_places = 4;
$format = "%.${decimal_places}f";
$formatted = sprintf($format,$number);
```

Comment: Im sorry, my question is say I have number "4". I wish for it to display as "4.00" and if I have "2.000000001" then it displays as "2.00" or if I have "3.2102" it will display as such. There is a NSNumber formatter on iPhone, what is the equivalent in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number format function:

```
<?php
$num = 43.43343;
$formatted = number_format(round((float) $num, 2), 2);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: You can round() the number (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) and then add formatting with the number_format() function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to display numbers to an inconsistent degree of accuracy. I don't understand what pattern you're trying to describe in your comment, either.

But let us suppose that you want the following behaviour: you want to express the number to 8 decimal places, and if there are more than 2 trailing zeroes in the result, you want to remove the excess zeroes. This is not much more difficult to code than it is to express in English. In pseudocode:

```
$mystring = string representation of number rounded to 8 decimal places;
while (last character of $mystring is a 0) {
    chop off last character of $mystring;
}
```

Comment: I am formatting a bitcoin amount, witch is calculated out to 8 decimal places, and always displays at least 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Using **preg_match** just get the zero ending with and then rtim it

```
<?php 
$nn = number_format(10.10100011411100000,13);
preg_match('/[0]+$/',$nn,$number);
if(count($number)>0){
    echo rtrim($nn,$number[0]);
}
```

Hope it will help you.